Simulating a basic bridge-rectifier circuit
I went through this SE post before asking my question:
How do you design a bridge rectifier circuit?
I have been continuously trying to simulate bridge-rectifier circuit in KiCAD and have kept failing. I have added GND reference for simulator (ngspice) in my circuit

Figure 1. KiCAD Schematic with Ground

Figure 2. Simulation results
I tried this in ngspice as well.
Here is my bridge_rectifier.cir
* this is a bridge rectifier
V1 a 0 sin(0 5 1k)
.model DMOD D (IS=65.4p RS=42.2m BV=1.00k IBV=5.00u
+ CJO=14.8p  M=0.333 N=1.36 TT=2.88u)
D1 a b DMOD
D2 b c DMOD
D3 c 0 DMOD
D4 a 0 DMOD
R1 b 0 1k
.tran 5u 5m
.control
run
plot v(a) v(b) 
.endc
.end


Figure 3. Output
I don't seem to be getting, this expected output.

Figure 4. Expected output
I tried using Multisim, but the online version is too limited and allows for only 5 components in a circuit.
Hoping to learn more about the grounding concept.

Can you at least give a summary of the issue, what is the output and what you expected it to be, so people don't need to follow external links?

Sorry @Justme I expected the output to be rectified as compared to input waveform. The output is in range of mV which is unexpected. I tried to draw out what happens on first and second half cycle of AC input, result here

Your source should be connected between a & c, not a & 0.

Please edit you post to include your images, so that users don't need to clock links.

Okays @MathKeepsMeBusy will do that. @ brhans I tried what you suggested,  ![V1 connected to c instead of 0](https://ibb.co/Z6Q8t4k) doesn't render for some odd reason.

In the toolbar above the edit window is a "picture" icon you can use to insert images.

@gitt - Hi, I've copied the images into SE image hosting from the external hosting links, and embedded those images inline in your question. FYI posts (Q&A) on SE should be self-contained. Links should only be used for supplementary (i.e. non-essential) information. However the images are essential to the question & the question would become useless for future readers, if the external image links died in future. FYI the syntax you mentioned ![V1 connected to c instead of 0](https://ibb.co/Z6Q8t4k) wouldn't render an image because the ibb.co link goes to an HTML page, not to an image.

@gitt - Hi, Where did the "expected output" image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the original webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + webpage URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page etc. TY

Your figure 3 has the expected output in blue. What is the problem then?

Despite it's many and serious limitations, even the CircuitLab simulator that's linked here on EE.SE, seems adequate to simulate a full-wave bridge reasonably well. The following schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
...produces the following simulation output:

If you're going to do much, you'll certainly want something better--but for a task this simple, it's reasonably adequate.
Bottom line: even though it's not particularly good, you're setting a really low bar here.

There is nothing wrong with the simulation. Here are the same results for LTSpice (notice the differential measurement, \$V_{in}-V_{low}\$):

If you just increase the amplitude of the input signal to a much larger value than the diodes forward voltages:

With the lower voltage amplitude, the diodes barely conduct at the maximum and minimum values of the input voltage. It is like each conducting diode was a large resistor at these points, so the input voltage, without the differential measurement, is approximately half the maximum and minimum voltage values (due to 0V reference at the load).

This is what your spice describes - you can see that the voltage source is not connected correctly and does not match your KiCAD schematic:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thank you @brhans for your help, I hope https://pastebin.com/QqdbsXj9 is readable. I cannot view input waveform properly as it is with respect to a different ground, any suggestions on that, the output is perfect now..
